# ActiveMQ replicated levelDB with zookeeper

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper, leveldb

I want to understand zookeeper's role in replicated leveldb for ActiveMQ broker.

1. About zookeeper election : How does zookeeper knows that out of all the clients connected to zookeeper, which clients are ActiveMQ brokers fighting to become master. Is there any particular key or configuration which is passed by all the brokers connecting to zookeeper which says that we (let say 3) ActiveMQ brokers belong to same environment and fighting to become master.
2. At what interval slave broker copy data from master broker ? Any corner cases where data might be lost ?
3. Does ActiveMQ provides guarantee of message ordering using replicated leveldb ? I am talking about the case when re-election of master happens while producer is sending messages in sequence to the broker?

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. By zkPath in the Zookeeper configuration and by broker name.
2. Each message is synced to a quorum (nodes/2+1) brokers before the transaction completes. So there is no sync interval, it's synced in real time. The cluster will no function unless you have a quorum of brokers online so there should be no data loss.
3. The messages are synced to a majority of the nodes in a synchronous fashion. At reelection, a node with the latest updates will be elected. Ordered messages should be no problem. However, it's generally problematic to rely critically on ordered messages in a message queueing. As a rule of thumb - message order will only be complete under "happy days". Dead letters, multiple consumers and so forth might as well mess up message order.

Comment: I have a test case: Let's say we have a node of 3 brokers in which B1 is master and b2,b3 is slave.
A messages(m1) is copied by b1 but not by b2 but the next message just after m1(let's say m2) is copied by b2 first and not by b1. In this case: (b1 has m1) and (b2 has m2) and if master goes down at this time and b1 becomes the master thn we will loose m2 message.

How does ActiveMQ takes care of this message loose ?

Comment: Nice explanation. Can you expound on why the order would be messed up if we have multiple consumers or dead letter queues?